# Why camera in KaiOS emulator (B2G) not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, emulation, b2g, kaios

I want to make a QR Scan with KaiOS technologies, but that is not working in the KaiOS emulator. I'm using emulator version 2.2. But, I try on the web browser, the camera is worked.

Comment: Please try something, and then post your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On KaiOS phones, you have to make use of `mozActivities` like below:

```
var cameraActivity = new MozActivity({
    name: "pick",
    data: {
        type: ["image/*"]
    }
});

cameraActivity.onsuccess = function () {
    console.log('The received photo blob is' + this.result.blob);
};

cameraActivity.onerror = function () {
    console.error('Unable to open camera from device ');
};
```

Kindly refer to this link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/Web_Activities) for further details.